# How to solve Kali Linux internet connection after installing Kali Linux tools on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, system-installation, internet

I have recently installed kali Linux tools on Ubuntu using katoolin but then I lost many things: internet access, some apps like vlc that I had installed, ...
How can I revert that.. I would even uninstall what I had installed if necessary. I need to solve this issue because it's been 2 weeks now..

Edit: more details

My initial system:
Ubuntu 18.04

How I installed kali linux

1. I installed katoolin
2. Run sudo katoolin then followed the instructions to install the rest of it.

Now when I run lsb_release -a it shows that I have now a full Kali Linux system:
Distributor: Kali
Description: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release: 2020.4
Codename: kali-rolling

Now anytime I try to connect to the internet whether by Wi-Fi or Ethernet it says "Activation of connection network failed"

I have also been for solutions from the internet but all of them require internet connection to connect while that's my primary problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more detail. Tell us what Ubuntu you are using,m tell us what commands you ran that caused the problem, and tell us what commands you are using that show the problem.

Comment: I have just edited the question